# SQLSTATE[HY093] : pdo statement during insert into mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here it is my php code to realize insert into db:

```
<?php

require_once "includes/db_data_inc.php";

try 
{
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name",$db_user,$db_pass);

    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $cathy = new patient($_POST['name'],
                         $_POST['surname'],
                         $_POST['address'],
                         $_POST['birth-place'],
                         $_POST['province'],
                         $_POST['dt'],
                         $_POST['gender'],
                         $_POST['select']);

    $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, 
                                            surname, 
                                            address, 
                                            birth_place,
                                            province,
                                            dt,
                                            sex,
                                            case) value (:name
                                                        :surname,
                                                        :address,
                                                        :birth_place,
                                                        :province,
                                                        :dt,
                                                        :sex,
                                                        :case)");

    $STH->execute((array)$cathy);

}
catch (PDOException $pdoe) 
{
    error_log($pdoe->getMessage());
    die("An error was encountered!");
}

?>
```

Here it is `db_data_inc.php` where are stored db_info and where I create the object patient

```
    $db_host = 'localhost';

$db_name = 'main_db';

$db_user = 'root';

$db_pass = 'root';

/* Create an object patient */

class patient
{
    public $name;
    public $surname;
    public $address;
    public $birth_place;
    public $province;
    public $birth_date;
    public $sex;
    public $case;

    function __construct($nm,$sur,$addr,$bp,$pr,$bd,$sx,$cs)
    {
        $this->name = $nm;
        $this->surname = $sur;
        $this->address = $addr;
        $this->birth_place = $bp;
        $this->province = $pr;
        $this->birth_date = $bd;
        $this->sex = $sx;
        $this->case = $cs;
    }

}
```

I get this error:

```
[10-Feb-2012 21:14:29] SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

But I didn't realize the reason...why I got this error? someone can help me? Where is the mistake?

Comment: I created the class. It must be return something?

Comment: @DamienPirsy Here I do the cast $STH->execute((array)$cathy);

Comment: If you var_dump($catchy), what does it say? is it the correct array? Btw, why build a class just for that, and not a simple array??

Comment: I come from java so I'm fell confortable with class

Comment: You might be using the wrong name placeholder; see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you use `:dt` as a placeholder, but in the class constructor you use `$this->birth_date`.

Once casted, this will create an array with index '`birth_date'`, which doesn't match with the named parameter `"dt"`: choose one or the other.

Comment: Now unfortunately another error come back: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: print_r($catchy) and see if all the array indexes are there and are correct, i.e. they match the placeholders, the column names..and this might also be related to the other answer ('case' being a reserved word both for SQL and php)

Comment: ok ok...I resolved anything...I made a mistake to write.excuse me...THANKS AGAIN SO MUCH!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the cause of your error, but in your insert statement, CASE is a MySQL reserved word and should be escaped with backticks.

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, 
                                        surname, 
                                        address, 
                                        birth_place,
                                        province,
                                        dt,
                                        sex,
                                        `case`) value (:name
                                                    :surname,
                                                    :address,
                                                    :birth_place,
                                                    :province,
                                                    :dt,
                                                    :sex,
                                                    :case)");
```