# How to check in PHP if more PDO parameters provided than needed

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

I have following piece of code (PHP 7.3.16) which retrieves some data from database (MySQL):

```
// db credentials
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "user";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "database";

// pdo
$dsn = "mysql:host=".$dbhost.";dbname=".$dbname.";charset=utf8";
$options = [
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);

// run sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar > ?";

$pdo_parameters = [ 1 ];
// this will produce no results without any error:
// $pdo_parameters = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute( $pdo_parameters );

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    var_dump($row);
}
```

If array `$pdo_parameters` contains only 1 element then everything works as expected and I receive a result. However when `$pdo_parameters` contains more than one I don't receive any results at all without any exception message. PHP errors are active, but I don't see any PDO error message. Why?

I would like to raise an PHP exception if there are too many parameters. Is that possible?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in /tmp/test:42 Stack trace: #0 /tmp/test.php(42): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /tmp/test.php on line 42
```

I have a huge code base and need in such cases a proper exception handling. However I don't understand why PHP doesn't raise an exception in that case. Is this just another PHP bug or if there is just no way for PHP (PHP C internals) to check if there are too many PDO parameters? I know how to check that by myself in plain PHP (could be pretty inaccurate though if we have "?" in some strings), but it would be better if PHP PDO extension would have a function to check such cases.

---

**EDIT:** It is a known PHP bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77490 (first report from 20 January 2019)

Comment: btw this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1376838 is buggy

Comment: That's a good question. Sometimes PDO complains about extra parameters and sometimes don't. But I don't know exactly how to switch it on. Can you try a named parameter?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php is about using named parameters

Comment: This page is about using bindParam, that can be used with **either** named or positional placeholders. And exactly opposite to your approach of using an array with execute

Comment: @YourCommonSense yeah, you're right, now i see it too. Yes that's indeed a different approach. Now edited my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491802/pdo-passing-extra-parameters-to-a-prepared-statment-than-needed

Comment: php bug tracker: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79568 (05.05.2020) and https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77490 (20.01.2019)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, that situation doesn't seem to throw exceptions nor trigger errors. [PDOStatement::execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) at least returns `false` so you can roll your own:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8mb4";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);

$sql = 'SELECT ? AS foo';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

if (!$stmt->execute([1, 2])) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Failed to execute statement');
}
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Not ideal but...

Comment: I hope that `$stmt->execute([1, 2]` works as expected and there are no additional issues here too.

Comment: PDO is in general quite pleasant to use but it's full of rough edges like this.

Answer (score -1):

To check what param were provided use this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php,

Also use param bindings to be absolutely sure that you have bind the params the right way:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: could you explain why `debugDumpParams` is useful in that case. PHP manual tries to describe something esoteric to me and I don't understand why is tht function even useful in that example. ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php )

Comment: Yeah straight away, I'll post a link to pastebin to show you how everything should have been done :)

Comment: First thing first, I think is showing the empty array only because what you should have done was print_r($row, true);

Comment: it seems to work, I receive an error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined` if I bind too many parameters. However I would like to use "?" instead of named parameters. Otherwise I will have to rewrite tons of code lines ...

Comment: Sorry but, why don't use "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN  ('.$params.')" and 
$params =  implode(",",$pdo_parameters);

Comment: If it was helpful, can you accept it as the right answer?

Comment: This is not helpful. You seems to be completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: :( stackoverflow is way meanier than I thought

Comment: Also nobody thought that SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar > *an array* doesn't make sense?
@YourCommonSense

Comment: you answer is okay, but your suggestion would imply that i'll have to rewrite many many lines of code and that's not practical and not ideal. Imho that's speicific edge case is a bug in PDO or just a missing hint on PHP PDO man page, I would open a bug request on PHP bug tracker later.

Comment: No man, it's not a bug.
I didn't see it before, but you have simply not thought that you are trying to make a wrong sql statement.
SELECT * FROM SOMETHING IN (just put here the imploded array) and I guarantee it's gonna work

Comment: `WHERE bar > ?` is just an **example**. It can be any other query. The question is not about this query **at all**

Comment: The issue isn't about trying to select something where the value is **in** an array, it's about the fact the array contains more parameters than placeholders.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that @iainn, I really didn't got the real problem.
Anyway :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461763/phps-pdo-prepared-statement-am-i-able-to-use-one-placeholder-multiple-times

Comment: :( my common sense is tingling

Comment: @YourCommonSense anyway I've start to read your answers of other questions, damn I'm starting to love you